# VB 2008/2010 - Get All Accounts on local Computer or Network

Tags: vb.net, windows, account

I had searched for a really long time now, but I can't find any results on Google, how to read out all Accounts on my local machine using VB.
I everytime only get results like 'finding IP addresses in local network' and so on.

But because I can see other accounts in my system control panel, I think there must be a possibility to read them out via VB. But how?!

Comment: Well, thats C#, it does not help me at all..

Comment: It's the same .NET classes, and using them is very similar in VB.NET and C#. Read the code, make an effort to convert them to VB.NET, and then when you run into difficulties you can post your code and ask a specific question about that problem.

Comment: Seriously? C# doesn't help you at all... ever heard of Google? http://bit.ly/1BAZHjw

Comment: Ok, thanks-.- already the first line of the translated code is rubbish, because the class DirectoryEntry does not exist in VB 2010!